# Django queryset regex filter gives (3692, 'Incorrect description of a {min,max} interval)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Using **Django 2.2** and **MySQL** database.

I have a field (`info`) in the table containing stringified JSON data. I want to filter the data matching the regular expression.

The example data in the `info` field is

```
[{"type":"button","data":{"link":"https://example.com","label":"Click Here","tracking":{"id":"E3s06x","tag":"btn1"}}}]
```

Where I want to match the expression

```
"tracking":{"id":"(\S+)","tag":"(\S+)"}
```

I tried using the `regex` filter in the Django ORM

```
query = query.filter(
  info__iregex=r'"tracking":{"id":"(\S+)","tag":"(\S+)"}'
)
```

But it is giving an error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3692, 'Incorrect description of a {min,max} interval.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces means in regex that certain text may apear serveral times, so you have used curly braces without esceping them. Try replace `{` with `\{` and analogically closing